# Find all polynomials $P(a) \in \mathbb R[a]$ such that $P(x + y + z) = \sum_{cyc}\frac{P(y)P(z)}{x^2}$

Tags: functions, polynomials

> Find all polynomials $P(a) \in \mathbb R[a]$ such that $$ P(x + y + z) = \frac{P(y)P(z)}{x^2} + \frac{P(z)P(x)}{y^2} + \frac{P(x)P(y)}{z^2}, \forall x, y, z \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$$

This problem is similar to another problem which is described as

> Given quadratic function $f(a)$ such that there exist reals $x, y, z$ $(y \ne z, z \ne x, x \ne y)$ satisfying $$ f(x) = yz, f(y) = zx, f(z) = xy$$
>
> Calculate the value of $f(x + y + z)$.

Let $f(a) = ma^2 + na + p$ $(m \ne 0)$. We have that $$\left\{ \begin{align} mx^2 + nx + p &= yz\\ my^2 + ny + p &= zx\\ mz^2 + nz + p &= xy \end{align} \right.$$

$$ \iff \left\{ \begin{align} (y - z)[m(y + z) + n] &= x(z - y)\\ (z - x)[m(z + x) + n] &= y(x - z)\\ (x - y)[m(x + y) + n] &= z(y - x) \end{align} \right.$$

$$ \implies \left\{ \begin{align} m(y + z) + n &= -x\\ m(z + x) + n &= -y\\ m(x + y) + n &= -z \end{align} \right.$$

$$ \iff \left\{ \begin{align} m(y - z) &= y - z\\ m(z - x) &= z - x\\ m(x - y) &= x - y \end{align} \right. \implies m = 1 \implies n = - (x + y + z)$$

$$ \implies p = \left\{ \begin{align} yz &- x^2 + x(x + y + z)\\ zx &- y^2 + y(y + z + x)\\ xy &- z^2 + z(z + x + y) \end{align} \iff p = xy + yz + zx \right.$$

$$\implies f(a) = a^2 - (x + y + z)a + (yz + zx + xy) \implies f(x + y + z) = yz + zx + xy$$

Okay, let's get back to the original problem.

Let $\deg P = q$, we have that $\displaystyle \deg\sum_{cyc}\frac{P(z)P(x)}{y^2} = 2(n - 1) \implies q = 2(q - 1) \iff q = 2$

Consider the case where $P(a)$ is a constant function.

Let $P(a) \equiv c, \forall a \in \mathbb R$. We have that $c = c^2 \cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{x^2} + \dfrac{1}{y^2} + \dfrac{1}{z^2}\right), \forall x, y, z \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\} \implies c = 0$.

$\implies P(a) \equiv 0, \forall a \in \mathbb R$.

We can't accurately compare the leading coefficient of both $\deg P$ and $\displaystyle \deg\sum_{cyc}\frac{P(z)P(x)}{y^2}$ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We evaluate the equation at $y=z=1$:
$$x^2 \left[P(x+2) - 2P(1)P(x)\right] = P^2(1)\text{ .}$$
On the left side we have a polynomial without a constant coefficient. Therefore this equation is only true for $P\equiv 0$ or $P\equiv \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore $P\equiv 0$ is the only solution for the original equation.